# Elemento tem o tipo any implicitamente ao tentar acessar uma propriedade de um namespace de módulo (objeto)

Tags: typescript, react

Funciona:

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fa';
...
const teste = 'FaAddressBook';
const Icon = Icons[teste];
```

Não funciona:

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fa';
...
const teste:string = 'FaAddressBook';
const Icon = Icons[teste];
```

Erro:

> ```
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/node_modules/react-icons/fa/index")'.
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/node_modules/react-icons/fa/index")'.ts(7053)
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas `props` do componente eu vou receber o nome do ícone como string e precisaria exibir ele, mas só funciona sem TypeScript.

Answer (score 6):

Você está recebendo esse erro porque, em TypeScript, módulos também são estaticamente tipados. Desse modo, quando você importa todos os ícones usando a seguinte notação:

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fa';
```

O TypeScript irá "definir" o tipo de `Icons` (também chamado de *module namespace*) como algo assim:

```
type Icons = {
  FaAccessibleIcon: IconType;
  FaAccusoft: IconType;
  FaAcquisitionsIncorporated: IconType;
  // ...
};
```

Desse modo, o TypeScript irá emitir um erro se você tentar acessar desse módulo uma propriedade que *pode* não existir (desde que a opção `noImplicitAny` esteja definida como `true`).

Para entender melhor o erro, basta pensar que uma string pode assumir qualquer valor de uma string, como `FaAccessibleIcon` (uma string que existe no módulo) ou `FooBarBaz` (uma string que *pode* não existir no módulo).

A partir do momento em que o compilador não tem certeza de que o que você está tentando acessar realmente está lá, o tipo `any` será atribuído, o que lança o seguinte erro no caso de `noImplicitAny` estar habilitada:

> ```
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type [...]
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type [...] ts(7053)
> ```

Existem diversas formas de se resolver esse erro. A mais simples delas é usar uma [asserção de tipos](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) (*type assertion*):

```js
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fa';
import { IconType } from 'react-icons/lib/esm';

const iconName: string = 'FaAddressBook';

// `Icon` é do tipo `IconType | undefined`. =)
const Icon = (Icons as Record<string, IconType | undefined>)[iconName];
```

<sup>[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/lffg/SOpt/blob/master/answers/458304/assert-module-namespace-member.ts)</sup>

Com o código acima, nos confirmamos <sup>(do verbo "*assert*" em inglês)</sup> ao compilador que o *namespace* `Icons` é do tipo que criamos utilizando o tipo embutido [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt). O tipo que criamos com o `Record` é equivalente ao seguinte:

```
type LooseIconsType1 = {
  [key: string]: IconType | undefined;
};

// É o mesmo que:

type LooseIconsType2 = Record<string, IconType | undefined>;
```

Nesse caso, estamos utilizando a asserção mais "segura", já que, caso você estiver com a opção `strictNullChecks` ativada, `Icon` poderá também ser `undefined` (já que o *union type* `IconType | undefined` foi utilizado), o que te obrigará a verificar a sua *existência* antes de utilizá-lo.

Se você não estiver preocupado com a segurança de tipos (o que é um erro, até porque um dos principais benefícios do TypeScript é a segurança adicional por ele trazida), você pode simplesmente desativar a opção `noImplicitAny` ou simplesmente fazer uma asserção ao tipo `any`:

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fa';

const iconName: string = 'FaAddressBook';

// `Icon` é do tipo `any`. =(
const Icon = (Icons as any)[iconName];
```

Mas eu realmente não recomendo essa última opção. Se você pode fazer algo um pouco mais seguro, não há porquê não o fazer. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

---

Uma outra opção seria utilizar [*type-guards*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) para isso. Mas como você pode verificar [aqui](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282) e [aqui](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732), essa ainda não me parece ser uma opção muito viável.

Para saber mais sobre as opções do TypeScript, leia [este documento](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Existe como fazer isso com um JSX.Element, nesse caso ai, você utilizou uma 'const' não tipada, como fazer funcionar num elemento react?